# TSQL Join to get all records from table A for each record in table B?

Tags: t-sql, join

I have two tables:

```
 PeriodId  Period   (Periods Table)
 --------  -------
 1         Week 1
 2         Week 2
 3         Week 3


 EmpId  PeriodId  ApprovedDate  (Worked Table)
 -----  --------  ------------
 1      1         Null
 1      2         2/28/2013
 2      2         2/28/2013
```

I am trying to write a query that results in this:

```
 EmpId  Period    Worked     ApprovedDate
 -----  --------  ---------  ------------
 1      Week 1    Yes        Null
 1      Week 2    Yes        2/28/2013
 1      Week 3    No         Null
 2      Week 1    No         Null
 2      Week 2    Yes        2/28/2013
 2      Week 3    No         Null
```

The idea is that I need each Period from the Periods table for each Emp. If there was no record in the Worked table then the 'No' value is placed Worked field.

What does the TSQL look like to get this result?

*(Note: if it helps I also have access to an Employee table that has EmpId and LastName for each employee.  For performance reasons I'm hoping not to need this but if I do then so be it.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
select p.empid,
  p.period,
  case 
    when w.PeriodId is not null 
    then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' End Worked,
  w.ApprovedDate
from
(
  select p.periodid, p.period, e.empid
  from periods p
  cross join (select distinct EmpId from worked) e
) p
left join worked w
  on p.periodid = w.periodid
  and p.empid = w.empid
order by p.empid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b9ee/16)

Comment: Wow, this was much more complex than I expected.  I kept thinking I was just missing a keyword or two in my efforts this morning and somebody's response would get me on the right track. This isn't what I expected at all.

Comment: @SailingJudo the key was to assign the `periods` to each employee first, then you can get the worked details. :)